# Bluemix PHP app fails on LDAP connection

Tags: php, ldap, ibm-cloud

This is a follow up ticket to one which was closed without answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515574/ibm-bluemix-authentication-using-tivoli-ldap

I have migrated a PHP app which requires LDAP authentication to Bluemix and I am getting the following error:

```
2016-01-08T10:28:53.87+0000 [App/0]      OUT 10:28:53 httpd   | [Fri Jan 08 10:28:53.869250 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 44:tid 139703240013568] [client 169.53.20.45:7120] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/utils/LoginLDAP.Class.php on line 21\n', referer: http://sbrooms.w3ibm.mybluemix.net/index.php
```

Please note that this is not the public Bluemix, but the internal IBM one (**w3ibm**.mybluemix.net), hence the connection to the LDAP server *should* be available.

Do I have to explicitly request the connection to the LDAP server, or something else is going wrong?

Thanks,
Pimmy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the LDAP-Extension for PHP is not installed on the WebServer. The `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ldap_connect()` suggests that.

You can check that by adding a page to your webserver with the following content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Call that website in a webbroser and check whether there is any trace of the LDAP-extension. If not, you will need to get that extension. As there are many different ways to install it (from recompiling PHP to a call to your systems package-manager) I need more information on how your system - and especially PHP - has been installed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Yes, you're correct - its the LDAP extension that is missing.